# 3D tensor * 2D tensor dot in Torch

Tags: torch

In Theano, when I have a 3D tensor `x` with shape [A,B,C] and a 2D tensor `y` with shape [C,D], then `theano.tensor.dot(x, y)` returns a 3D tensor with shape [A,B,D].

What would be the equivalent operation in Torch? `torch.dot` doesn't seem to do that, and `x * y` and `torch.mm` complain that they want a 2D tensor for both arguments, and `torch.bmm` wants 3D tensors for both arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @smhx proposed, the possible solution is to repeat the second tensor (there's a way to do it without memory allocating) and then perform a batch matrix matrix product:

```
function repeatNoCopy(tensor, k)
    local tens_size = tensor:size():totable()
    return torch.expand(tensor:view(1, unpack(tens_size)), k, unpack(tens_size))
end

A = torch.rand(3, 2, 5)
B = torch.rand(5, 4)
B_rep = repeatNoCopy(B, 3)

result = torch.bmm(A, B_rep)

print(result)
> [torch.DoubleTensor of size 3x2x4]
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to expand y to be of size [A,C,D] and then use torch.bmm. Look at the documentation of torch.expand or torch.repeatTensor.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How would the code look like? From the doc, it seems that repeatTensor creates a copy? I don't want that.